# When should you check the validity of Context in an async method in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous

I have an async function in Flutter that performs a lengthy IO operation, like a network fetch. Depending on the result of the operation, I show a dialog with a Success or Failure message. Then I use `setState()` to update the UI.

```
setState(() {
  _waitingForContent = false;
});
```

The `build()` method checks this flag and either shows a wait cursor or the actual content.

I need to use the current BuildContext to show the dialog. But since the dialog is brought up after an async gap, I have to check the validity of the context before using it:

```
if (!context.mounted) return;
```

Otherwise,

```
showDialog(context, result);
```

A simplified version of my code is here:

```
Future<void> downloadContent () async {
  setState(() {
    _waitingForContent = true;
  });
  bool result = await fetchContent();  // a lengthy network operation
  setState(() {
    _waitingForContent = false;
  });
  
  // we are across an async gap, so the context may not be valid
  if (!context.mounted) {
    return;
  }
  showDialog(context, result);
}
```

The above code seems to work fine, but I am not sure if I am testing it properly by simulating all possible timing-sensitive scenarios.

Specifically: should I put the `context.mounted` check before or after calling `setState()` ?
The context can become invalid when executing the line `await fetchContent()`.
So should I just discard the screen and quit without calling `setState()`:

```
  if (!context.mounted) {
    return;
  }
  setState(() {
    _waitingForContent = false;
  });
```

I am worried that this may end up showing an indefinite wait cursor under some circumstances.

Comment: Once your state is unmounted, any change to it like setState is rather pointless. So, perform your future-completion, then check mounted, and if not mounted, quit.